# Two Sum Pair (not unique)

Tags: c, sum

I am trying to print all pair of number in an array that sum up to a number ,however the logic of the code seem correct but i can't find where segmentation fault bug is coming from.Please can anyone help me review this code and tell me what is wrong:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int compare(const void *l, const void *r)
{
        return *(int *)l - *(int *)r;
}
int **twoSum(int *arr,int sum,int size)
{
        // create a result variable
        int **ret;
        int* result;
        int i;
        for (i=0;i<size;i++){
                // subtract it from the sum to find the difference
                int diff = sum - *(arr+i) ;
                // loop and find each diff in the array
                result= (int*)bsearch(&diff,arr,size,sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]),compare);
                // to subarray
                if(result!=NULL){
                        printf("Found item = %d\n", *result);
                        int a[2] = {arr[i],*(result)};
                        ret[i] = a; // 
                }
                else{
                        printf("could not find item = %d\n", *result);
                        continue;
                }
        }

        return ret;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
        int arr[9]={1,2,4,3,6,2,7,0,10};
        int** res = twoSum(arr,9,9);
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<9;i++){
                printf("[%d,%d]\n",res[i][0],res[i][1]);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: strongly suggest using a debugger (perhaps `gdb`)

Comment: OT: regarding: `int main(int argc, char const *argv[])`  This will cause the compiler to output two warning messages about unused parameters.  Suggest using the other valid signature for `main()`  `int main( void )`

Answer (score 0):

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 -c "untitled2.c" -o "untitled2.o" 

untitled2.c: In function ‘twoSum’:

untitled2.c:17:49: warning: conversion to ‘size_t {aka long unsigned int}’ from ‘int’ may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]
result=    (int*)bsearch(&diff,arr,size,sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]),compare);
                                             ^~~~

untitled2.c:22:28: warning: ‘ret’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
                     ret[i] = a; //
                        ^

Compilation finished successfully.
```

when there are warnings, then the output from the compiler: "Compilation finished successfully" only means the compiler used some work around for the problems,  It does NOT mean the generated code is correct.

regarding:

```
untitled2.c:22:28: warning: ‘ret’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
```

and

```
int **ret;
```

the pointer to a pointer `ret` is never initialized to point to some memory that the application owns (perhaps via `malloc()` )   so, if your using visual studio in debug mode, the stack has been initialized to all 0x00.  Then `ret[i]` is some location near address 0 (which an application never ever owns)  This is a very good reason for a seg fault event.